# Djano Windows Authentication on Development Server

Tags: python, django

I am developing a django web app on windows server 2016 in which I am using Windows Authentication, but when I am using on production - `request.META['REMOTE_USER']` it was working fine but when I am using the same code on development environment it was giving Key error. I have checked it but didn't find REMOTE_USER anywhere.

Comment: Your webserver has to be configured to set the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable, so Django could use it. From the docs:

When the Web server takes care of authentication it typically sets the REMOTE_USER environment variable for use in the underlying application.

Comment: Yes you are right but why the Webserver is not setting the REMOTE_USER for development environment ex. while debugging and setting the same variables on production server.